# Form freezes/crashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, performance

I have some jQuery that resets selects/dropdowns if the user changes the option selected in the previous dropdown. But when I include this jQuery it causes my form to freeze/crash sometimes - it happens after about 30 seconds of clicking around the form.

Can anyone spot anything wrong with this code? This is the jQuery code that seems to be causing the issues:

```
   // 1. Resetting Fields
age_select.on("change", function() {
    let currentCol = jQuery(this).val();
// When age is changed reset other dropdown (by setting value to the default one)
// and trigger change for the event handler to be called
    subject_select.attr("data-column", currentCol).val('subject-fill');
    area_select.attr("data-column", currentCol).val('location-fill');
});

//2. Resetting Fields - BELOW PART IS CAUSING THE FORM TO CRASH SOMETIMES 
// if subject is changed reset location and trigger change
subject_select.on("change", function() {
    area_select.val('location-fill').trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsbin or codepen.io/pen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you have some issue with the `area_select` event handler such that you might be triggering another change that creates an infinite loop (if for example that one triggers a change event on subject_select).

Your post is too ambiguous without a working(broken) example though.